# TwitterBootstrapMVC change input name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am migrating my application from MVC3 (aspx) to MVC5 (razor). I am trying to change the input name from Client.FirstName to FirstName, using:

```
 @(Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.Client.FirstName).Data(new {@name = "FirstName"})
    .Id("FirstName"))
```

I get:

```
<input name="Client.FirstName" class="form-control" id="FirstName" type="text" value="" data-name="FirstName">
```

I used the following helper in MVC3:

```
 public static string ExTextBox (this HtmlHelper helper, string name, object value, bool readOnly, string Label)
            {
            string HTML = "";
            //if (readOnly) HTML = String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", name, value);
            if (readOnly)
                HTML = value != null ? value.ToString() : "";
            else
                HTML = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox(helper, name, value).ToString() + System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessage(helper, name, "*");
            HTML = AddCellsAndLabel(HTML, name, Label);
            return HTML;
            }
```

In the view:

```
<%= Html.ExTextBox("FirstName", Html.Encode(Model.Client.FirstName), Model.IsReadOnly, null)%>
```

I tried the following in Razor View:

```
  @Html.ExTextBox("FirstName", Html.Encode(Model.Client.FirstName), Model.IsReadOnly, null)
```

I get the following (showing):

```
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" /><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
```

Since I am not experience to figure out how to fix the helper; I tried to use twitterBootstrapMVC.

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Why would you want to do that - it would no longer bind to your model - which is why you cant override the name attribute.

Comment: Hav eyou used [DisplayName("FirstName")] attribute for this?

Comment: @Ratatouille, That has nothing to do with setting the name attribute of an input.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do. Why do you want to change the name attribute and break model binding? Perhaps post the outcome you want (you can always use `@Html.TextBox() and add the class name and data-name attribute if your trying to style it)

Comment: I tried @Html.TextBox(), got: <input name="Client.FirstName" id="Client_FirstName" type="text" value="">.  I am using formcollection in the controller.

Comment: No idea why you would want to use form collection instead of model binding, but the html helpers are designed to be used with model binding, so either create the html manually or use `@Html.TextBox("FirstName", new { @class = "form-control")`. And what output are you expecting from your helper (which make so sense at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
new { Name = "FirstName" }
```

instead of

```
new { @name = "FirstName" }
```